# Nested Aura Components are not showing up in a Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have created a lightning app with Aura Component Bundles which is working fine as a standalone application and also as a Lightning Page.

I want to create a VF page using these Aura Components. I'm not quite sure what am doing wrong. I didn't want to share the original code, so following is a similar scenario.

**TestVFPage.vfp**

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:TestAppForVF", function(){
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:ParentComponent",
                                   "",
                                   "myDiv",
                                   function(component){
                                       console.log("ParentComponent loaded successfully in VF page");            
                                   });
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**TestAppForVF.app**

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp">
    <c:ParentComponent />
</aura:application>
```

**SelectedOption.evt**

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="SelectedOption" type="String" default="" />
</aura:event>
```

**ParentComponent.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:registerEvent name="registeredSelectedOption" type="c:SelectedOption" />
    
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
        <lightning:select aura:id="mySelect" label="" required="true" variant="label-hidden" >
            <option value="1" text="One" />
            <option value="2" text="Two" />
        </lightning:select>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Click" title="Click" onclick="{!c.onClick}"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
        <c:ChildComponent1 />
        <c:ChildComponent2 />
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</aura:component>
```

**ParentComponentController.js**

```
({
    onClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("Button Clicked!!!!");
        var selected = component.find("mySelect").get("v.value");
        console.log("From ParentComponent.cmp == Selected: "+selected);
        var evt = $A.get("e.c:SelectedOption");
        evt.setParams({
            SelectedOption: selected
        });
        evt.fire();
    }
})
```

**ChildComponent1.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:handler event="c:SelectedOption" action="{!c.selectedOption1}" />
    <aura:attribute name="showIt" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showIt}">
        <div>
            <p>I am in Child Component ONE !!!</p>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

**ChildComponent1Controller.js**

```
({
    selectedOption1 : function(component, event, helper) {
        var selected = event.getParam("SelectedOption");
        console.log('From ChildComponent1 - Selected: '+selected);
        if(selected == "1"){
            component.set("v.showIt", true);
        }else{
            component.set("v.showIt", false);
        }
    }
})
```

**ChildComponent2.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:handler event="c:SelectedOption" action="{!c.selectedOption2}" />
    <aura:attribute name="showIt" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showIt}">
        <div>
            <p>I am in Child Component TWO !!!</p>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

**ChildComponent2Controller.js**

```
({
    selectedOption2 : function(component, event, helper) {
        var selected = event.getParam("SelectedOption");
        console.log('From ChildComponent2 - Selected: '+selected);
        if(selected == "2"){
            component.set("v.showIt", true);
        }else{
            component.set("v.showIt", false);
        }
    }
})
```

This is what it shows in the console.log. Notice the text from child components is not showing.
[image: Error1]

This is from an Aura application which is working fine:
[image: Success1]
[image: Success2]

Also, I had to change the SelectedOption event's access to global in order to escapse this error: **This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed: c:ParentComponent$controller$onClick [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {c:ParentComponent$controller$onClick}**

Q1. Where am I going wrong?

Q2. Is there a specific way to create the child components in a VF page or just create the parent component and it automatically creates the child components (nested components).

Hope I have given all the details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mention in the question that I had created a Managed Package in the org and these components are from a different namespace. Following are the modified files:

**TestVFPage.vfp**

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("myNamespace:TestAppForVF", function(){
        $Lightning.createComponent("myNamespace:ParentComponent",
                                   "",
                                   "myDiv",
                                   function(component){
                                       console.log("ParentComponent loaded successfully in VF page");            
                                   });
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**TestAppForVF**

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://myNamespace:ParentComponent" />
</aura:application>
```

As *@sfdcfox* has mentioned, I am not adding any component in the application. Everything else is the same.

(edit: added the dependency tag in the aura:application)

Answer (score 1):

With Lightning Out, you must have a "dependency app." This is where you define the dependencies for the component so they can be delivered to the client. In other words, your TestAppForVF must look like:

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp">
  <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:SelectedOption" type="EVENT" />
  <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:ParentComponent" />
</aura:application>
```

Do **not** put any components other than `aura:dependency` in the `aura:application`. They will be created/instantiated, but not visible on the page. The dependency app is not meant to be rendered at all, but instead to tell the runtime which markup needs to be downloaded so the client can run.

Note that only "dynamically" created components, and dynamically referenced events (e.g. $A.getEvent or $A.get("e.ns:someEvent") need to be referenced as a dependency. Static dependencies are automatically detected by the framework.

You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_dependency.htm).

*(edit: corrected expected markup, added explanation.)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The documentation says, Use the <aura:dependency> tag if you fire an event in JavaScript code and you’re not registering the event in component markup using <aura:registerEvent>, but I am registering the event in the ParentComponent - correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @Apz I missed that in your code. You're right that you wouldn't need to include `c:SelectedOption` in this case. However, you still *must* list an aura:dependency for `c:ParentComponent`, because it is not statically referenced elsewhere in your code. However, also note that it doesn't *hurt* to include a component, even if it is statically referenced (the component won't be "loaded" more than once). You must have, at minimum, all top-level components you intend to use referenced in the dependency app.